# How can I mock the fs module using memfs in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am currently trying to mock out the `fs` module by using mocks in Jest and replacing `fs` functions with `memfs` methods. I am using TypeScript, so I want to mock out the module in TS as well instead of JavaScript.

I found a project that creates a mock of `fs`, but it is written in JS [here](https://github.com/dyoung2019/memfs-jest-mocks/blob/main/__mocks__/fs.js)

However, this seems to not work well with my tests, so I wanted to recreate it in TS, and rewrote it as such

```ts
/* eslint-env node,mocha,jest */
import { fs as fsm, IFs, vol } from "memfs";

const fs: IFs = jest.createMockFromModule("fs");

fs.fromJSON = (json, path) => {
    vol.fromJSON(json, path);
};

fs.toJSON = () => vol.toJSON();

fs.reset = () => vol.reset();

const mergedMock = {
    ...fs,
    ...fsm,
    __vol: vol,
    __fs: fsm
};

export default mergedMock;
```

My tests are giving me errors:

```ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: fake_fs.fromJSON is not a function

      231 |
      232 |             for (let i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
    > 233 |                     fake_fs.fromJSON({
          |                             ^
      234 |                             "/test": real_fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, cases[i][0])).toString()
      235 |                     });
      236 |
```

Where:

```ts
const real_fs = jest.requireActual("fs");
jest.mock("fs");
const fake_fs = require("fs");
```

Is there something I am missing when creating this mock?

EDIT: Changed `const fs: IFs = jest.createMockFromModule("fs");` to `const fs = jest.createMockFromModule<typeof import("fs")>("fs");` as I realized I am trying to build on the wrong type. It now looks like:

```ts
/* eslint-env node,mocha,jest */
import { fs as fsm, vol } from "memfs";

const fs = jest.createMockFromModule<typeof import("fs")>("fs");

fs.fromJSON = (json, path) => {
    vol.fromJSON(json, path);
};

fs.toJSON = () => vol.toJSON();

fs.reset = () => vol.reset();

const mergedMock = {
    ...fs,
    ...fsm,
    __vol: vol,
    __fs: fsm
};

export default mergedMock;
```

However, I cannot add new functions on top of `fs` now like you can in JS. This is important to me because I still need methods like `fs.readFile`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try mocking the return values, something like this:

```
jest.mock('fs');
const fake_fs = require('fs');

// mockreturn value
fake_fs.mockReturnValue(() => {
  fromJSON: () => {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
  // and so on with other methods
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but unfortunately there are a lot of tests where I would have to implement this functionality so that is not feasible now. I did realize that there was an issue in how I was creating the mock and made an edit with what I believe is the real issue now

Comment: If DRY its your concern and you'd mock the same way 'fs' why don't just create a global mock and import it to all your test with import '@mocks/yourMockedFsFile' ?